# String of special characters

Tags: c, string

I am required to use string of special characters like: `!,",#,~` etc

If I do :

```
char arr[10]  = "''''''''''";
char arr1[10] = "!!!!!!!!!!";
char arr2[10] = "##########";
printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n",arr,arr1,arr2);
```

then the `printf` prints the string and some garbage.

Where I am going wrong?

Comment: You presumably didn't read the compiler warning you got about the "excess element in initializer" or something like that. (hint: C strings are 0-terminated.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Characters arrays ( also known as C strings ) are null terminated, so you need an extra index in the array to store the null character. If you need a string of 10 characters, you need to create a string which can store 11 characters ( the extra character for the null character `'\0'` )

So, change your code to

```
char arr[11]  = "''''''''''";
char arr1[11] = "!!!!!!!!!!";
char arr2[11] = "##########";
printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n",arr,arr1,arr2);
```

or even better, as suggested by @TheParamagneticCroissant , you can do

```
char arr[]  = "''''''''''";
char arr1[] = "!!!!!!!!!!";
char arr2[] = "##########";
printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n",arr,arr1,arr2);
```

With this, the compiler will find out the length by itself.

Comment: Better yet, `char arr[] = "...";` and the compiler will figure out the size automagically.

Comment: @TheParamagneticCroissant , yes, that's better.

Comment: If you indend the strings to be exactly 10 characters long, no more, no less, then type: `char arr [10+1]`. Self-documenting code.

Comment: @Lundin, may be an idea to use [10+1], but who uses C may know strings are 0 terminated! I think (when we uses constant) the use of var[] is better. I think is better also declare: const char var[]="xxxxx"; !

Answer (score 1):

You need one byte space more for the nul character:

```
char arr[11]  = "''''''''''";
char arr1[11] = "!!!!!!!!!!";
char arr2[11] = "##########";
printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n",arr,arr1,arr2);
```

Or simply:

```
char arr[]  = "''''''''''";
char arr1[] = "!!!!!!!!!!";
char arr2[] = "##########";
printf("%s\t%s\t%s\n",arr,arr1,arr2);
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope you got your answer, however, just to clarify things a bit more, for `%s` format specifier in `printf()`, as per `C11` standard document , chapter §7.21.6.1,

> s
>
> If no `l` length modifier is present, the argument shall be a pointer to the initial element of an array of character type. Characters from the array are
>   written up to (but not including) the terminating null character.

That means, the argument pointer supplied for `%s`, should be a pointer to `char`, having a `null` in the end to mark the *end-of-array*. Thus, null-terminated `char` array are considered *strings* in C.

Now, coming back to your case,

```
char arr[10]  = "''''''''''";
```

you have exactly 10 initializer to a 10-element `char` array. thus, no space for null-termiantor. When you sypplu the base address of this array as an argument for `printf()` to be used for `%s`, `printf()` does not know where to stop, thus reading beyond allocated memory which in turn invokes [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

**Solution:**

1. Leave the size allocation to the compiler, best approach.

   ```
    char arr[]  = "''''''''''";
   ```
2. or, atleast, allocate enough memory so that the null-termiantor can be accomodated.

   ```
    char arr[11]  = "''''''''''";  //10 elements + 1 null
   ```

Please do the same for `arr1` and `arr2` also.

Comment: Sir!!!! Your case I have tried but it gives garbage value along with string. Second one is fine as it worked.

Comment: @AbhijatyaSingh Did you do the same for all the arrays?

Comment: Sir!!! I am on linux centos7 x64 bit and using gcc-4.8.3. May be this is the issue.

Comment: @AbhijatyaSingh 1) please don't call me sir. 2) no, that should not be an issue. kindly cross check your actual code, surely you're missing something. the logic stands. :-)